# Why is prototype undefined on return from constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, return, instance

If I use a return statement in a constructor, isn't it considered an instance? Or does the return statement make it a regular function?

```js
function ClazzA() {};
ClazzA.prototype.go = 1;

function ClazzB() {
    return {};
};

ClazzB.prototype.go = 1;

var a = new ClazzA();
var b = new ClazzB();

console.log(a.go); //1
console.log(a.constructor); //ClazzA()
console.log(a instanceof ClazzA); //true
console.log(b.go); //undefined
console.log(b.constructor); //Object()
console.log(b instanceof ClazzB); //false
```

Comment: You return empty object from constructor. If you return number or string it works as expected. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new explanation, what happens if constructor returns new object

Comment: @YHarry Please do not drag on a question by editing in follow-up questions in your question. You can ask for clarification in the comments under an answer, but it is up to that person if they want to give any further help or if you need to figure out things on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the `new` operator works in  JavaScript. If the constructor returns an object reference, then that's the value of the `new` expression. Your constructor creates and returns an empty (plain) object, so that's what's assigned to the variable "b".